# Switch Case within Do .. While + Error in Java

Tags: java, switch-statement, case, do-while

So I am trying to create a program for an assignment where the user would pick an animal, and depending on that animal (dog/chicken/fish), how many legs it has. If the user did not select one of the 3 animals, the game would then ask the user if they would like to play again. If the answer is y, then the program would start over, but if it is n, then the program would stop. The error is near the bottom where it states "String gameAnswer = input.nextLine();". It says that I have to rename gameAnswer. Could anyone help me fix this so that the program would work?

Thanks in advance!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Choose an animal: ");
    String text = input.nextLine();
    char n;
    char y;
    char gameAnswer = 'n';

    do
        {
        switch (text) {
        case "dog":
            System.out.println("How many legs does a dog have?");
            int dg = input.nextInt();

            if(dg == 4)
            {
                System.out.println("You win!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You lose!");
            }
            break;

        case "chicken":
            System.out.println("How many legs does a chicken have?");
            int chkn = input.nextInt();

            if(chkn == 2)
            {
                System.out.println("You win!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You lose!");
            }
            break;

        case "fish":
            System.out.println("How many legs does a fish have?");
            int fsh = input.nextInt();

            if(fsh == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("You win!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You lose!");
            }
            break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        }
    while(gameAnswer == 'y');
    System.out.println("I don't know that animal. Do you want to try again? (y/n)");
    String gameAnswer = input.nextLine();
    }
```

Comment: The only error I get is the last line of `String gameAnswer = input.nextLine();`, because `gameAnswer` is already defined...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prompting and reading of the line should be within your loop

NOT

```
while(gameAnswer == 'y');
System.out.println("I don't know that animal. Do you want to try again? (y/n)");
char gameAnswer = input.nextLine();
```

BUT

```
System.out.println("I don't know that animal. Do you want to try again? (y/n)");
gameAnswer = input.nextLine();
while(gameAnswer == 'y');
```

ALSO

`gameAnswer` is already defined, so do not redefine it.

AND ALSO

You probably want `gameAnswer = input.nextLine().charAt (0);`

**EDIT**

also move

```
System.out.println("Choose an animal: ");
String text = input.nextLine();
```

to after

```
do
```

Comment: Ok so I am a little confused. How do I make the gameAnswer consistent in the program? By this I mean, how do I get the program to prompt for the first statement (Please choose an animal) again if I have to rename gameAnswer? Don't I need to have gameAnswer where I placed it?

Comment: No, you need it where I placed it.  As you have already defined `gameAnswer` once within the relevant scope, you do not need to do it again.  If you replace the `NOT` code with the `BUT` you should be right.

Comment: Ok so I have no errors shown, but when I run the code, I am running into problems.

***1. If I enter in the wrong animal (such as cat), the program then tells the user that it does not know that animal and asks the user if they would like to try again. After I enter y, the program then tells the user again that it does know the animal and asks the user if they would like to try again.***

Comment: 2nd problem is when I enter the correct animal and enter either the right or wrong number of legs, after the program says "You lose" or "You win", it says **I don't know that animal. Do you want to try again? (y/n)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
 at AnimalGame.main(AnimalGame.java:64)"**

Comment: I have added an EDIT for problem 1

Comment: As for problem 2, please consider what logic you want and think how, you can arrange the program to flow like you want.  Also consider using `continue` before the `break` to go to the top of your loop

Comment: I really appreciate your help.

The 1st problem has been finally solved.

For the 2nd problem, I'm not really understanding what you mean. Is there a way to explain that more?